# C# Regex Parse Arguments / Identifiers

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, command-line, command

I am currently thinking of realizing some sort of command managing system, nothing big and just for fun purposes(e.g. IRC Bot, ...)

I am doing quite well in C# and all of the logic is more or less set up, but since I'm a noob in terms of RegEx, I can't find a nice solution for parsing all the arguments and identifiers. I did imagine something like "identifier parameter1 'parameter2 with space' parameter3". That is my "concept" and in my opinion it's not a good solution just to use the String Methods "Split, Replace, Substring, ..." but RegEx would do the job.

So, long story short: Is this even possible with RegEx? How would one parse that correctly with RegEx? Are there better solutions in terms of how to handle the arguments?

I thought of creating a "pattern" for each command and then letting a parser gather all the strings. In this case the User would not need to use "" to specify the arguments, but I thought RegEx would be the better solution...

Well that's about it, hoping for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this regex helps you:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(inputStr, @"'[^']*'|\S+");
```

If you run it usint the input: "identifier parameter1 'parameter2 with space' parameter3" then you will get a collection with 4 elements:

```
identifier
parameter1
'parameter2 with space'
parameter3
```

**EDIT**

I have made an improoved version:
 - supports `''` as an escape for `'`, when inside a param with spaces

```
var matches =
    Regex.Matches("identifier parameter1 'parameter2 with ''space''' parameter3",
        @"'(?:[^']|'')*'|\S+")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Value)
        .Select(s => s.StartsWith("'") && s.Length >= 2 ?
            s.Substring(1, s.Length - 2).Replace("''", "'") : s)
        .ToArray();
```